# Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria) MongoDB query C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is possibe to do a query  `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and delete all the documents found? I'm using mongoDB c# driver, I took the idea from the mongo repository but I'm not inheriting any base class on my entities, so I don't have a class and the access to the generic property "id"

The following code won't work:

```
foreach (T entity in this.collection.AsQueryable<T>().Where(criteria))
{
    this.Delete(entity.Id);
}
```

any advice?

Comment: Why would you want to delete each document, individually, by bringing back a large list of matching documents, only to send it down, one by one to delete?

Comment: @WiredPrairie yeah that could be another option nice suggestion!

Comment: Honestly, it's the difference between an efficient app and a slow app. I wouldn't use the code you accepted in a production system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create following generic extension method to remove all documents matching your criteria. But collection's Remove method requires some MongoQuery to find document which should be removed. You can construct query which selects document by id if you will pass id selector:

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this MongoCollection<T> collection,
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria, Func<T, BsonValue> idSelector)
{
    foreach (T entity in collection.AsQueryable<T>().Where(criteria))
        collection.Remove(Query.EQ("_id", idSelector(entity)));
}
```

Usage:

```
people.RemoveAll(p => p.Age > 50, p => p.Id);
```

Comment: thanks men! passing the id selector to the collection, did the trick! I never imagined in that way!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pass your query to `Remove`. For example, removing all documents that have a `name` property with the value `"test123"`:

```
collection.Remove(Query.EQ("name", "test123"));
```

This way, it's a single call to remove all matching documents, rather than first fetching matches, and then removing them individually (or even as a group using the `$in` operator).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
collection.Remove(Query<T>.Where(criteria));
```